# Why -inf when calculation expression that is controlled

Tags: python, python-3.x, largenumber, infinity

I am doing a calculation with variable values:

```py
b=49277625229919252619702799653707265870395898977145078030839752

n=22112825529529666435281085255026230927612089502470015394413748319128822941402001986512729726569746599085900330031400051170742204560859276357953757185954298838958709229238491006703034124620545784566413664540684214361293017694020846391065875914794251435144458199

c=-3.2029790664620333e+67
```

and the value I am calculating is:

```py
B = (b + (n - b*b) * c)
```

This returns `-inf` which should not be, given that I am not constrained by memory space (I have more than 10 gigs where I am doing this).

Is this problem fixable?

Edit : I would also like to know the reason why this is happening so that I can avoid future mishaps.

Comment: There is a limit on how large a float can be in python. To check the limit you can: import sys
print(sys.float_info.max) which returns 1.7976931348623157e+308

Comment: I like how the two answers only answer "Is this problem fixable", but not why it's happening. hmm

Comment: Ah, I should have mentioned that I would like to know that too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your operation returns `-inf` because it overflows the limit of `float`. You can use `sys.float_info.max` to check maximum float value supported  by the implementation. Generally this value is `1.7976931348623157e+308`. So the numbers above this limit will be represented as `float('inf')` if positive or `float('-inf')` if negative.

Now, in order to solve your problem you can use the builtin [`decimal`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/decimal.html) library in python.

**Try this:**

```
from decimal import Decimal

b = Decimal(b)
n = Decimal(n)
c = Decimal(c)

B = (b + (n - b*b) * c)
print(B)
```

**Output:**

```
-7.082691727141074913216311547E+326
```

Comment: Nice workaround. Thank you. Although both answers worked for me, due to the time complexity of using this, I am accepting this as the accepted answer.

Comment: You don't actually need `Decimal` for this, given that all the numbers involved are integers (in the sense that `c == int(c)`). Python has infinite precision for integers, so if you do `B = b + (n - b * b) * int(c)` you'll get a precise answer!

Answer (score 2):

Another solution can be done using mpmath library which is a library with  arbitrary precision

```
from mpmath import mp, mpf

# set 50 decimal point precision
mp.dps = 50

#...
b=mpf(b)
n=mpf(n)
c=mpf(c)
B = mp((b + (n - b*b) * c))
```

Output:

```
mpf('-7.0826917271410749132163115458418859131992983363200556e+326')
```

Comment: Thank you for letting me know this method. This seems more flexible, but the time complexity is higher than the accepted answer's one, and hence my decision. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

My calculator answered -708269172714107481699009991286024451899843951069764894337265485724940929397877002420223612611538343533719511941925009995267129421537088615912195341304356911711190148667675445629255480078613791447051517048459934380810882287658436814218846510469903536007822812720891745018494205080747380297200346292734129604101022854921969160248